# How to get content_aware_access in reports sdk?

Tags: google-admin-sdk

I want to use Reports API - ADMIN SDK to get content_aware_access list, but i can't find any api to return this.

First I set the security level at https://admin.google.com/u/1/ac/security/context-aware and then check it at https://admin.google.com/u/1/ac/reporting/audit/context_aware_access , but now I need to search through api sdk.

Please tell me where to find this sdk? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The information you are looking for is contained in [Reports API: Admin Activity – Security Event Names](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/reference/activity-ref-appendix-a/admin-security-events).

Before you implement the request in the language of your choice, I recommend you to test it with [OAuth Playground](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/reference/activity-ref-appendix-a/admin-security-events)

Instructions:

- Chose the scope `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.reports.audit.readonly` (Step 1)
- `Exchange authorization code for token` (Step 2)
- Insert a Request URI and `Send the request` (Step 3)

Chose the URI according to your requirements based on the documentation for [Admin Activity Report](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/guides/manage-audit-admin.html).

Sample URI:

`https://www.googleapis.com/admin/reports/v1/activity/users/all/applications/admin`

This will retrieve all your security settings.

If you look for something more specific, for example events with the name `CREATE_ACCESS_LEVEL_V2` - request the URI

`https://www.googleapis.com/admin/reports/v1/activity/users/all/applications/admin?eventName=CREATE_ACCESS_LEVEL_V2`